# Everything executes but the query...what am I missing?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a file that receives uploaded images from another page. The images are received and saved on the server (that part is working) the query is not. I manually typed the query into phpMyAdmin with dummy values for the file name and it works. I put that dummy query into this code and it doesn't work. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$ds  = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
$storeFolder = 'img';   
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];              
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `photos` (photo_id, file_name) VALUES ('', '".$_FILES['file']['name']."');"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_error()` PS: guys please give him a chance to debug it himself

Comment: or maybe mysql_connect()

Comment: or checking if mysql_query() returned `false`, indicating an error occurred.

Comment: is the photo_id column set to autoincrement? Perhaps changing your query to `"INSERT INTO photos (file_name) VALUES ('$_FILES['file']['name']')"`?

Comment: @zerkms The difficult in using echo/var_dump/error is that this page is being called through a javascript post method, how would I echo errors from a server-side page to a client side page?

Comment: autoincrement and primary key

Comment: @mpratt yes, auto increment. Tried your method too, no dice. It seems that the query is not executing at all (like I said with dummy data).

Comment: @SuperNoob: you could still use `echo` and look at the ajax response using chrome dev tools -> network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that photo_id is auto incremented here are some fixes to your code:

```
<?php
$ds  = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
$storeFolder = 'img';   
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];              
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO photos (photo_id, file_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."')"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

This way you should be able to debug your code.
Now if you need to get the result from a Javascript call, you should use AJAX.

Check here:

[Send a request to a php page and then get back results using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830583/send-a-request-to-a-php-page-and-then-get-back-results-using-ajax)